# AttributeError: module 'DiscordoragiSearch' has no attribute 'isValidMessage'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module which has the following code

```
import DiscordoragiSearch

...

@Discord.client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message recieved')
    #Is the message valid (i.e. it's not made by Discordoragi and I haven't seen it already). If no, try to add it to the "already seen pile" and skip to the next message. If yes, keep going.
    if not (DiscordoragiSearch.isValidMessage(message)):
        try:
            if not (DatabaseHandler.messageExists(message.id)):
                DatabaseHandler.addMessage(message.id, message.author.id, message.server.id, False)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            pass
    else:
        await process_message(message)
```

Here is the relevant code from `DiscordoragiSearch.py` which is in the same directory as the other file.

```
#Checks if the message is valid (i.e. not already seen, not a post by Roboragi and the parent commenter isn't Roboragi)
def isValidMessage(message):
    try:
        if (DatabaseHandler.messageExists(message.id)):
            return False

        try:
            if (message.author.name == USERNAME):
                DatabaseHandler.addMessage(message.id, message.author.id, message.server.id, False)
                return False
        except:
            pass

        return True

    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return False
```

This method is defined in the base of the module yet when I run the code I get the following error

```
File "/home/james/discordoragi/roboragi/AnimeBot.py", line 225, in on_message
if not (DiscordoragiSearch.isValidMessage(message)):
AttributeError: module 'DiscordoragiSearch' has no attribute 'isValidMessage'
```

Full code for both modules can  be found [here](http://github.com/jwolff52/discordoragi) if you would like any more information I will try my best to provide it, this has been stumping me for over a month now so any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: It's not a method, it's just a function. And the error you have in the title is different from the one in the body of your question. Which one is it?

Comment: Crap sorry. It is the one in the question, in an attempt to generalize the error I screwed up horribly, sorry.

Comment: @jwolff52 You can edit your question and just make whatever corrections you need to.

Comment: @idjaw Yep all done.

Comment: Also, I can't find a single class in your repository. In Python, you aren't forced to write class definitions for everything, so just call them modules unless they are actually classes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, the reason why no search results are coming up in the repo is because it is a forked repo. GH doesn't give search results off of a forked repo. It's going to be hard to search for matching code unfortunately

Comment: Ok I am 90% everything should line up now, had renamed to module to avoid a possible name conflict and didnt push.